# Water leak from car. Part identification

Tags: head-gasket, water-pump, water-leak, water

A have a leak from my car that is easily visible and accessible. I do not know what part it is or wether it's an indication of another issue within the car. Please see attached picture.  My finger marks where it is leaking from. It is literally leaking out of the rubber cap.[image]

Comment: It might help to know what the car make/model/year/engine is to help place what you're talking about.

Comment: It looks like some kind of capped off branch from the thermostat or water outlet. Maybe a heater line?

Comment: @Paulster2 it's a Renault Scenic 05 plate.